# Cannot Get Discord.js to Mention User in Command

Tags: discord.js, command, dice, slash, mention

Alright, so I'm working on making a d100 slash command for Discord.js v13, the app works almost perfectly I've tried a few things but have run into a wall. The bot gives the undoctored user name, without a mention and ignored nicknames, rather than the nickname.

This is the closest I've gotten to my goal (a command that @mentions the nickname)

```
 //Remember to run " node deploy-commands.js " to register your commands!


    const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
    
    module.exports = {
        data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
            .setName('100')
            .setDescription('rolls a 100'),
        async execute(interaction) {
            await interaction.reply(`${interaction.user.username} rolled ${Math.round(Math.random() *100 )}`);
        },
    };
```

Please Ignore the node command at the top I tend to forget to node when adding new commands for slash commands.

trying to change the **${interaction.user.username}** for nicknames, mentions, etc lead to:

```
undefined rolled 44
undefined rolled 55
etc
```

rather then the username or a @mention

on a few options I got the return:

```
function userMention(userId) {
    return <@${userId}>;
} rolled 5
```

if anyone could give me any tips I would be grateful I'm pretty sure its the **${interaction.user.username}** that is my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use `${interaction.user.username}` which is invalid and will always give you `undefined`, so to mention someone you have to use `interaction.member.user` and for username: `interaction.member.user.username` ([docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Interaction?scrollTo=member))

Comment: Nope, that is completely valid - [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Interaction?scrollTo=user)

Comment: **interaction.member.user** was what I needed and btw **interaction.user** and **interaction.member.user**  both work the over-all issue was the **.username** in my code.

Thank you this is now working as I need it to